# The meaning of the expression あたいがとる

Tags: verbs

I was reading [a short text on Aozora](http://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/001475/files/51105_51785.html):

> お星さま
>   小川未明
>
> 澄{すみ}ちゃん、澄{すみ}ちゃん、なにあげよう。
>   あのお星{ほし}さま、とっておくれ。
>   あんまり高{たか}くて、とれません。
>   そんなら、**あたいがとってみよう**。
>
> お星{ほし}さま、お星{ほし}さま、なにあげよう。
>   のどがかわいた、水{みず}おくれ。
>   あんまり遠{とお}くて、いかれません。
>   そんなら、わたしが下{お}りていこう。

I found the phrase あたいがとってみよう。 I suppose the original expression must be あたいがとる。

My question is about とる.  Isn't it a transitive verb?  It doesn't make sense to me in this expression.  Please help me understand the meaning of the expression.

Comment: Makes perfect sense because the object of とってみよう has already been mentioned, which is あのお星さま.

Answer (score 4):

In this case あたい is being used as a 1st person pronoun meaning "I." So basically that line means "if you can't, then I'll try to take it." The が is referring to the speaker as the subject, and the object of とる is omitted. Basically it's あたいが（あの星を）とってみよう. Sumi wants the star, but the unnamed person can't reach, so Sumi decides to have a go.

Comment: I initially thought so too. But in the second verse it's `わたし`...

Comment: "The unnamed person"??  If that were not お星さま, this would be a failure as a poem.  The entire conversation looks to be between 澄ちゃん and お星さま.  A star saying that another star is too high up to catch is poetry.

Comment: 澄ちゃん addresses herelf as あたい and お星さま addresses itself as わたし.  「あのお星さま」 is a different star than the お星さま in the title (that speaks half the lines).

Comment: I thought this way: in the 1st stanza someone (maybe sumi's mon or dad) asks sumi what she wants, sumi says she wants a star but they say they can't reach it, so sumi decides to give it a try, and in the 2nd stanza she talks to the star "what do you want" and it says it wants water, so she invites it to come closer... (clever girl!) So I think the conversation in the 1st stanza is between sumi and someone, and the 2nd is between sumi and the star.

Comment: I interpreted it the same way Chocolate did. @Tokyo Nagoya, I'd encourage you to make your own answer if you think mine is incorrect. Looking at it in its entirety I can see why your way could be right, but there *is* a little room for interpretation here.